# Tricky numpy indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have values in a 2D array called `a`.
I have a second array, `C`, in which I have indices which refers to cells in `a`.
This array's dimensions are therefore `(M, N, 2)`.

I want to construct the output of dimensions `(M, N)` which is made of the values of `a` from the indices stored in `C`.

This is a pythonic way to do so:

```py
a = np.arange(20).reshape(-1, 5)
print(a)
# [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
#  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
#  [10 11 12 13 14]
#  [15 16 17 18 19]]

C = np.array([
    [[2, 0], [3, 1]],
    [[0, 0], [1, 4]],
    [[2, 2], [1, 1]],
    [[0, 0], [1, 1]],
])


output = np.array([[a[cell[0], cell[1]] for cell in row] for row in C])
print(output)

# [[10 16]
#  [ 0  9]
#  [12  6]
#  [ 0  6]]
```

I guess there is a more numpy-ic way which would be much more elegant but, more importantly, much more efficient to do the same thing.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: `a[C[...,0], C[...,1]]`?

Comment: @Divakar I never cease to be amazed by Numpy's indexing trickery...

Comment: @Divakar Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Divakar: This is indeed the solution.
I'm so amazed... Didn't event know that was valid code.
Thanks a lot.

```py
>>> output = a[C[..., 0], C[..., 1]]
>>> output
array([[10, 16],
       [ 0,  9],
       [12,  6],
       [ 0,  6]])
```